# Unable to load data from a text file in windows machine using load data local (hive)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have a java program to load data from a text file into hdfs. The query which I am trying to execute is as below.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'file:///D:/test/values.txt' INTO TABLE hive_box.vh_9856_Stg
```

However on executing this query I am receiving an exception as

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: IllegalArgumentException
>   java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 2:
>   D:

I tried to remove '`file:///`' from the query. Still I am getting error.

Please assist me to resolve this issue